# Allow html styling of text from XML element.

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have been using abit of xslt to style my xml into something readable. However there is one thing I have not been able to figure out.

I was woundering how you can apply stylying to the text inside the xml elemnts. for instance this is what part of my xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="mystylesheet.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<Collection>
     <Tals>
          <Indent="0">Weapon Training</Talent>
          <Cost>1</Cost>
          <Description>Confers <b>proficiency</b> of <i>two weapons</i>, either  melee or ranged. This talent make be aquired multiple times</Description>
     </Tals>
```

I would like to know how I could get my description element to output in a html format.. so ou can see the bold text and italic text.

This is how I am catching my Description element from my xml in mystylesheet.xsl

```
Description: </b><xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My understanding is that you like to output the content of Description like it is (containing text and html tags)?

Comment: yea i would like to make the text inside description look and act exactly like html.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is right you like to copy the content of Description.
This could easily done by changing the `<xsl:value-of select="Description"/>` to

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Description/node()"/>
```

To make it work you have also to add an "identity transform template"

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Update:
Alternative you can also use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Description/node()"/>
```

But the "identity transform template" is the better solution, because it is possible to add still more specialized  templates.

Comment: okay i will try this... im not really sure about your second example with the nodes however... I will try and read up about that.

Comment: I tried the first part of your example that didnt work.. in trgards to your second example I dont understand the "@|node()"

Comment: you have to add this template `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">` to your xls file. to make the `<xsl:apply-templates select="Description"/>`work. So you need both.

Comment: @HurkNburkS: Did you try this?

Comment: yes.. but i need to do it again cause it didnt work originally.. more like I dont think I coded it well enough. I am still working on it.